# Asp table created dynamically gets invisible when table cell is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am working on a project in that I have a drop down for selecting classes.Then for the selected class its timetable is displayed.I have created this timetable using an asp table dynamically and have added click event on table cell.But when I click the table cell whole table gets invisible.I have used asp table before for doing same type of things,at that time also I got the same error but at that time it got resolved when I placed the create table method outside the post back method in page load event.But here I am calling my create time table method on drop down selected index change.I have tried by placing my asp table inside update panel but that also haven't solved my problem.

Following is my aspx code

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnltimetable" runat="server" Visible="false">
       <asp:Table ID="tbltimetable" CssClass="timetable" runat="server"  CellSpacing="25" GridLines="Both"></asp:Table>
    </asp:Panel>
```

Following is my cs code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UserType"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        filldrpclass();
    }
}
//method for making timetable
protected void makeTimetable()
{
    string periodno = "";
    //getting all periods
    sql = "SELECT * FROM tblperiodtime order by periodnumber";
    ds = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    //getting timetable of the selected class
    sql = "SELECT t.*,s.subjectname,tc.teachername FROM tbltimetable t join tblsubject s on s.sshortname=t.subject join tblteacher tc on tc.tshortname=t.tchrshortnm where t.classcode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "' order by t.period";
    DataSet dsTimetbl = new DataSet();
    dsTimetbl = obj.openDataset(sql, Session["schoolcode"].ToString());
    DataRow[] drtimetbl;        
    //To clear previously added rows
    tbltimetable.Rows.Clear();        
    //some entries exists for periods
    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++)
            {
                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    tc.CssClass = "periodTableCelldays";
                    tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                    if (j == 0)
                        tc.Text = "Periods";
                    else
                    {
                        //get week day name from integer value
                        string weekday = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[j];
                        //for displaying text in the form of Weekday eg MON
                        tc.Text = (weekday.Substring(0, 3)).ToUpper();
                    }
                    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    tbltimetable.Rows.Add(tr);
                }
                else
                {
                    tc.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        //showing period number and timing
                        tc.CssClass = "periodtime";
                        tc.Text = "0" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["periodnumber"].ToString() + "<br/>" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["starttime"].ToString() + "-" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["stoptime"].ToString();
                        periodno = "0" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["periodnumber"].ToString();
                        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                    }
                    else
                    {                           
                        //selecting particular period
                        drtimetbl = dsTimetbl.Tables[0].Select("period='" + periodno + "' and weekday='" + j + "'");
                        clickablecell ctCell = new clickablecell();
                        ctCell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                        if (drtimetbl.Length != 0)
                        {
                            ctCell.CssClass = "viewlessonplan";
                            Random rnd = new Random();
                            ctCell.ID = j + "-" + periodno + "-" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["starttime"].ToString() + "-" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["stoptime"].ToString() + "-" + "Edit-" + drtimetbl[0]["id"].ToString() + "-" + "Subject-" + drtimetbl[0]["subjectname"].ToString() + "-" + "Teacher-" + drtimetbl[0]["teachername"].ToString();
                            //ctCell.ID = drtimetbl[0]["id"].ToString() + "-" + (i * j + i + j).ToString();
                            ctCell.Text = drtimetbl[0]["subjectname"].ToString() + "<br/> by<br/>" + drtimetbl[0]["teachername"].ToString() + "<br/>Edit Period";
                            ctCell.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "defColor=this.style.backgroundColor;  this.style.backgroundColor='LightGray';");
                            ctCell.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=defColor;");
                            ctCell.Click += new clickablecell.ClickEventHandler(textcell_Click);
                        }
                        else
                        {                               
                            ctCell.Text = "Create Period";
                            //weekday-period-starttime-stoptime
                            ctCell.ID = j + "-" + periodno + "-" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["starttime"].ToString() + "-" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i - 1]["stoptime"].ToString()+"-Create-0-Subject-null-Teacher-null";
                            ctCell.CssClass = "noperiod";
                        }
                        tr.Cells.Add(ctCell);
                    }
                    tbltimetable.Rows.Add(tr);
                }
            }
        }
        tbltimetable.Visible = true;
        pnltimetable.Visible = true;
    }
    //if no entries exists for periods
    else
    {
        tbltimetable.Visible = false;
        pnltimetable.Visible = false;
        lblalerts.Text = "Time Table/Lesson Plan not created yet";
        lblalerts.Visible = true;
        divalerts.Visible = true;
    }
}
//table cell's click event
void textcell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    makeTimetable();
    clickablecell _ctcell = (clickablecell)sender;
    string weekday = (_ctcell.ID.Split('-')[0]).ToString();
    string period = (_ctcell.ID.Split('-')[1]).ToString();
    string starttime = (_ctcell.ID.Split('-')[2]).ToString();
    string stoptime = (_ctcell.ID.Split('-')[3]).ToString();
    string operationtype = (_ctcell.ID.Split('-')[4]).ToString();
    string timetableid = (_ctcell.ID.Split('-')[5]).ToString();
    string subjectname = (_ctcell.ID.Split('-')[7]).ToString();
    string teachername = (_ctcell.ID.Split('-')[9]).ToString();
    if (operationtype == "Edit")
    {
        lbledit_heading.Text = "Edit Period";
        //for preselecting subjects when edit period is selected
        foreach (ListItem li in drpSubjects.Items)
        {
            if (li.Text == subjectname)
                li.Selected = true;
        }
        //for preselecting days
        foreach (ListItem li in drpDays.Items)
        {
            if (li.Value == weekday)
                li.Selected = true;
        }
        //for preselecting teachers
        foreach (ListItem li in drpteachers.Items)
        {
            if (li.Text == teachername)
                li.Selected = true;
        }
    }
    else
        lbledit_heading.Text = "Create Period";
    //filling controls in popup
    filldrpsubjects();
    filldrpteachers();
    lnkHidden_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
}
```

Please help.Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Try removing

```
Visible="false"
```

from your definition of your asp:Panel.

If you wish to have it hidden on initial load then add it to your PageLoad method like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["UserType"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        filldrpclass();
        pnltimetable.Visible = false; //initially hidden
    }
}
```